# How should we show path between two latitudes & longitudes in google maps using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift3, google-directions-api

Here, 
i have source latitude & longitude
in the same way i also have destination latitude & longitude
Now, i want to show the path between these two lat & long's

```
sourcelatitude = 12.9077869892472
sourcelongitude = 77.5870421156287

print(sourcelatitude!)
print(sourcelongitude!)

destinationlatitude = 12.907809
destinationlongitude = 77.587066

print(destinationlatitude!)
print(destinationlongitude!)
```

Could any one help me with this

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282635/7250862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw polyline using Google Maps in custom view with Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282454/draw-polyline-using-google-maps-in-custom-view-with-swift-3)

Comment: @RajeshkumarR am getting error in 5th line(the code which is in the link provided by you). i.e., use of unresolved identifier JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let origin = "\(12.9077869892472),\(77.5870421156287)"
let destination = "\(12.907809),\(77.587066)"
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
  if(error != nil){
    print("error")
  }else{
    do{
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
      if json["status"] as! String == "OK"
      {
        let routes = json["routes"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ 
         for route in routes
         {
          let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"] as! [String:String]
          let points = routeOverviewPolyline["points"]
          let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeColor = .blue
            polyline.strokeWidth = 4.0
            polyline.map = mapViewX//Your GMSMapview
        }
       })
      }
    }catch let error as NSError{
      print(error)
    }
  }
}).resume()
```

Comment: from 4th line it is coming out of the loop. i.e., last line(.resume)

Comment: @ammateja Use break point in 5th line. It will run from 5th line after few secs because it will be running in a background thread.

Comment: i did what you said, but the app is getting crash at
           
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)

here is the crash report:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSThreadException', reason: 'The API method must be called from the main thread'

Comment: it is working fine now. I tried to pass lat & long's dynamically, at that time it's not working
Here is my code
let soulocation: [String:Any] = Constant.getPickupLocation()
let sourlat = soulocation["lat"]
let sourlong = soulocation["long"]
let destlocation: [String:Any] = Constant.getDestinationLocation()
let destlat = destlocation["lat"]
let destlong = destlocation["long"]
        
let origin = "\(sourlat),\(sourlong)"
let destination = "\(destlat),\(destlong)"
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)")

Answer (score 0):

```
 var aPosition =   "30.9621,40.7816"
        let bPosition = "26.9621,75.7816"
        let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(aPosition)&destination=\(bPosition)&key=\(your google key)"
        //let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=\(aPosition)&destinations=\(bPosition)&key=AIzaSyCaSIYkkv41RTn5vFLiSoZFlCUhIg-Db5c"
        print(urlString)
Alamofire.request(urlString)
            .responseJSON { response in
  if let array = json["routes"] as? NSArray {
                    if let routes = array[0] as? NSDictionary{
                        if let overview_polyline = routes["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary{
                            if let points = overview_polyline["points"] as? String{
                                print(points)
                                // Use DispatchQueue.main for main thread for handling UI
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    // show polyline
                                    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath:points)
                                    self.polyline.path = path
                                    self.polyline.strokeWidth = 4
                                    self.polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                                    self.polyline.map = self.mapView

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```